# Really basic stuff with Glide

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-glide

So I have a basic question about Glide. Im doing an android test application and just want to transform an image to fit the screen.

This was the old code:

```
Bitmap background, backgroundresized;

(...)

//load image
background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.gamebackground);

}

void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

if(first_time){
width = canvas.getWidth();
height = canvas.getHeight();
backgroundresized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, width, height, true);
first_time=false;
}
canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundresized, 0, 0, null);
}
```

This isn't the best approach to fit a screen, I know, I use this and drawable-xhdpi/xxhdpi/xxxhdpi folders.

But how to use Glide to do this, and hopefully recycle the image if the user comes back to this screen?

Comment: Glide provides override size. Read documentation: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-image-resizing-scaling

Comment: Im not working with ImageViews.

Comment: Then it has custom target, resizing work same way. You can add like .into(SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(width,height){...})

Comment: Thanks, what comes after (width,height)? I have no idea.

Comment: You really need to read some documentation buddy :) https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Custom-targets

Comment: I still dont get it how in my example I can save the result in the bitmap "backgroundresized" using Glide.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154820/discussion-between-vurgun-m-and-csant85).

Answer (score 0):

Allright, there are different ways to do, but easy way to keep static instance of that class because glide stays as inner class when you try to assign to upper.  check following sample code 
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

```
    static Bitmap somebitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int myWidth = 512;
        int myHeight = 384;

        Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load("URL")
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(myWidth, myHeight) {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        somebitmap = resource;
                    }
                });
    }
```

}

Comment: Throws a null object reference on the bitmap when the code tries to use it to draw.